# When series of values occurs report value in adj. cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of machine states "idle" "running" "complete" "error" "hold" with the time stamp of each state. in the third column I've calculated the duration for each state.
I'd like to know the duration of the "running" state, but only when it is proceeded by an "idle" and followed by a "complete" state.

so something like if the series "idle" "running" "complete" report duration of "running"

---

Solved using =IF(AND(C23="idle",C25="complete"),D24)

Comment: Can you include a picture of your data?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://s15.postimg.cc/7d9ol506z/Capture.png)

Comment: what have you tired ?

Comment: I'm currently trying to do it with "if" or "if(and)".
I previously used a pivot table to calculate avg/min/max for all the duration.

Comment: I've found a solution.
=IF(AND(C23="idle",C25="complete"),D24)

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(H13="idle",H15="complete",H14="running"),I14)